# What is the tP statistic from ANGSD?

Tags: statistics, phylogeny, phylogenetics, exon

We were looking for genetic diversity in the exon level of an MHC transcript and analysing the data under [ANGSD](http://www.popgen.dk/angsd/index.php/ANGSD) (Analysis of next generation Sequencing Data) written in C++

We used ANGSD to calculate Thetas and Tajima D neutrality tests and one of the thetas was a pairwise theta, however I am unsure what this means and how it differs from Tajima's D?

http://www.popgen.dk/angsd/index.php/Thetas,Tajima,Neutrality_tests

We then divided the tP over length of each exon to find genetic diversity in the exon level. However, as I am very interested in statistics, if someone could explain what the tP statistic means exactly it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't explain it to you directly, you might check out the section on theta estimators in [Korneliussen et al. (2013)](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-14-289) which is cited on the above ANGSD wiki page. The equation for this estimator in this paper traces back to the [original Tajima (1989).](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1203831/pdf/ge1233585.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Theta but Tajima D is a population genetics test that assumes constant sample size. When the number of segregating sites (non-conservative sites in an alignment) significantly differs from pi (Nei's p-distance between a pair of sequence) one possibility is selection given a constant population size.

What Tajima found was cool: under neutrality this relationship conforms to a beta distribution. Just to explain that again so the nucleotide differences between every pair of sequences in an alignment (pi) against the total number of possible mutations conforms to a beta distribution for a constant population size under neutrality.

Its a cool idea - like really cool - but the violations - any level of 'extinction' will skew the distribution, population movement and importantly so could a bias in sampling.

So what you get is a pair-wise matrix at 5% critical probability. If your data entirely conformed to Tajima's D it would be an amazing result, but that is not the result you are looking for. So if Tajima D gave a particular pair <0.05  AND it was supported by other tests THEN (sounds like code) it provides a basis to consider selection as an explanation.

Again I don't know Theta but if both tests were congruent for putative selection I'd say that was reasonable. However, Tajima D alone is not a cool result, its cool theory however but not cool in practice. I hope that explains it?

Note: did any one ever follow this up in trees? Cool if they did because there will be a relationship between the balance of a tree (e.g. Bayesian 'Skyline' plots) and Tajima D.